# How do I implement payload analytics in Watson OpenScale?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-openscale

How do I get access to the payload data in Watson OpenScale?

What languages are supported for querying the data (e.g. SQL)?

Will OpenScale provide a UI for payload data visualization in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Payload data is stored in the Watson OpenScale Data Mart. Supported DBs for the Data Mart are Postgres & DB2.

Additionally, the IBM Watson OpenScale Python SDK can be used to access Payload Logging. Please see the relevant section in the associated documentation:

http://ai-openscale-python-client.mybluemix.net/

Data visualization is available via Watson Studio:

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/refinery/visualizations.html